# ValueError: read of closed file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to parse some pages using **BeautifulSoup**, but for some links the opener doesn't work. Here is the code for opener:

```py
class URLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"
    def http_error_default(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers):
        if errcode == 403:
            raise ValueError("403")
        return super(URLopener, self).http_error_default(
            url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers
        )
```

Now when it is trying to open and parse some pages with this code:

```py
opener = URLopener()
page = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features='lxml')
links = soup.findAll("a", href=True)
```

it works fine. But when it gets to a link like this:

> http://scholar.google.com/citations%3Fview_op%3Dsearch_authors%26hl%3Den%26mauthors%3Dlabel:deep_learning

it suddenly stops and shows an error:

[image]

How can I filter the searched pages to avoid this issue? I don't necessarily want all the pages in the search result.

Comment: You could try `urllib.parse.unquote(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your URLs are in a quoted form. This can easily be removed using Python's [`unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urllib%20parse%20unquote#urllib.parse.unquote) function as follows:

```
import urllib.parse


opener = URLopener()
page = opener.open(urllib.parse.unquote(url))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features="lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a", href=True)
```

This would convert the example URL you have given to the following format:

```
http://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:deep_learning
```